# Looking for a word for "not up for discussion"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that means "not up for discussion", "will not discuss this topic", a topic that is out of bounds. noun/adjective?  Example, "Several months ago, our daughter made talking about her weight _______".

Edit:  Please excuse my failure to follow the proper format.  I believed that the word began with a "v" but to cite where I searched?  Seemingly everywhere online. I found numerous options including "out of bounds" and "off limits" but not the one word that I knew existed. My search brought me here so clearly I'd been looking for a time.

However, thank you.  I know the post is on hold but I was able to view some of the answers to my question regardless and the answer I was looking for was provided.  As I type this, I can't "see" who posted it but thank you to that person.  I'd also like to thank/cite my 82 y/o mom because as I was viewing the answer here, I was on the phone with her and she immediately knew the word I was searching for.

It seems like it would be wrong of me to post the answer since it was provided by someone else so again, thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: For some reason, *off-topic* is the first word that springs to mind here. I would say *unmentionable* if its plural noun form didn't mean undergarments, and a word like that--one that has a root that is nearly synonymous with *talk*--would sound somewhat redundant in that sentence  as stated. Therefore, some may suggest nonspecific words, e.g off-limits or...inadmissible, a family fave, which also applies to evidence, etc.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information is needed to help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: Well, you *can't* post an answer, as long as the question is on hold. And you wouldn't be taking credit away from the author just by identifying which of the posted answers is the one you wanted. But, even better, you can acknowledge the best answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. (Also, you should be able to see the authors' names — they are to the right of their pictures/identicons. Some of them might not be immediately recognizable as *names,* though; they include initials, userNNNNNN, nicknames, joke names, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

Per Merriam-Webster

[verboten](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verboten) (adj): forbidden, prohibited by dictate

"We're Jewish, so talking about Santa Claus at home is *verboten*."

"Hate speech is *verboten* on this campus."

Comment: That's made it into English now? Great!

Comment: You can also try the English counterpart "forbidden"..

Comment: Using the (almost identical) German word for something which already exists in English would seem very unnecessary and strange for people who know German.

Comment: Well, English _is_ known for "borrowing" words from other languages...

Answer (score 3):

My grandmother never spoke of her family

my mother told me the topic was **taboo** as she lost them when young.

> 1.1 A practice that is prohibited or restricted by social or religious custom.

<sup>from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/taboo</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The subject is ***[off-limits:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-limits)***

> not to be interfered with, considered, or spoken of
>
> - the subject of sex was off-limits in her family

(M-W)

> Several months ago, our daughter made talking about her weight “off-limits".

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a compound word: [*off-limits*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-limits):

> used to say that people are not allowed to talk about something

<sub>(source: Merriam-Webster, English Language Learners Dictionary)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**non-grata**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/non+grata)

> Not welcome; not approved

and

**non grata** [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/non-grata)

adjective; informal

> unwelcome

As in:

He felt rather non grata!

and your sample sentence:

"Several months ago, our daughter made talking about her weight **non-grata**!

Comment: Your link isn't properly structured, so it doesn't work. There is 'gratis' and 'persona non grata' but I'm not sure about 'non-grata' on its own, as English.

Comment: The referenced dictionaries support "non grata" without "persona", so it is technically correct, although it certainly seems an unusual usage.